# Can I handle my own legal problems?

Tags: contract-law, iraq

Just a general question, it's so expensive to get lawyers these days and my business isn't making any money. I live in Iraq, can I manage my own legal problems such as customer complaints, land laws etc?

Comment: I've never heard of being required to get a lawyer.

Comment: Are you asking if you *can* or if you *should*?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Businesses are routinely required to get a lawyer if they are parties to litigation.

Comment: @bdb484 That's a good point, I hadn't considered it from the perspective of the business. Thanks.

Comment: @bdb484 That is true for companies/corporations. Businesses can be sole traders.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Iraqi legal system so I can't say whether you are allowed to appear in court without a lawyer. As to whether its a good idea, it depends.

Many Western systems have a "small claims" court (or similar name) which deals with simple low-value cases like collecting payment owed by a customer. The UK limit is £10,000. These systems discourage you from hiring lawyers and try to make the whole thing as simple as possible. If Iraq has something like this then you should go ahead and use it.

Once you get above the small claim level you should get a lawyer. Even if you are allowed to represent yourself its a false economy: a lawyer will know about the steps you have to take, the documents you have to file, deadlines, fees etc. Doing this yourself is like trying to learn chess by reading the rules the day before a game with a Grand Master: the professional lawyer on the other side will always be three steps ahead of you and you will wind up with conversations like this:

> You: Here is the evidence that proves I am in the right.
>
> Judge: Its too late to introduce that. You should have included it in your submission to the court last month. You lose. Goodbye.

Comment: In Germany, there's no small Claims, but the Amtsgericht handles stuff up to some limit, above that you **require** a lawyer (Anwaltszwang/pflicht)... I *think* small claims is a Common Law thing, while Code Civil handles need for a lawyer differently.

Comment: @trish [That is not correct](https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/dealing-with-customers/solving-disputes/european-small-claims-procedure/index_en.htm). The small claims procedure is available in every EU country except Denmark.

Answer (score 0):

> Just a general question, it's so expensive to get lawyers these days
> and my business isn't making any money. I live in Iraq, can I manage
> my own legal problems such as customer complaints, land laws etc?

You can try to manage to start a business without a lawyer, but this is a horrible idea. The odds that your business will fail and that you will lose a great deal of money are increased at least tenfold if not more, by trying to start a significant business without legal advice.

Legal advice is a necessary cost of running a business. While there might be some aspects of the law where you can do it yourself, or learn how to do it once from a lawyer and then continue to do work without legal assistance, in general, if your business is anything of consequence, you need some significant legal counsel about something at some point in the early stages of establishing your business. The exact details will vary by type of business, but there is almost always some legal issue that requires you to get professional guidance if you are going to be successful.

If your business isn't making any money and doesn't have prospects of doing so in the near future, you should close up shop and seek employment from someone else. The whole point of a business is to make money.

If your business needs to endure a period of not making money in a business plan that will eventually cause it to be profitable, you need working capital raised from investors to start it with any prospect of success. Legal fees need to be part of your initial working capital budget, because one of the things you almost surely need legal counsel for is raising working capital for your business. Sometimes, a lawyer can take an interest in your business in exchange for advice offered "in kind" in lieu of a cash payment.

If you don't have the working capital necessary to cover necessary start up expenses like legal fees, license fees, advertising, the costs of payroll until you become profitable, and other operating costs until you become profitable, you should refrain from starting a business at all until you have a way to raise enough start up capital to get you to a point where you can become profitable.

Comment: I have to strongly disagree with this answer. I think it's fair if we are assuming a highly capitalised startup with lots of employees and a sophisticated business plan etc. But it's important to remember that the vast vast majority of businesses are small (probably 1 person or a family) enterprises perhaps involving a retail shop or a local service. It would be crazy in almost all such cases to waste money on a lawyer unless you find yourself involved in litigation, or it is for a specific one-off need (e.g. buying a shop).

Comment: @JBentley There is always litigation or a one-off need, and people who don't budget for the need routinely see all of their efforts squandered.

Comment: I just don't think that applies to e.g. your local fruit stand, domestic cleaner, newsagent, gardener etc. other than on rare occassions. To be fair though, it's possible our experiences differ between the USA (known to be fairly litigious) and the UK (where costs risks and court procedure rules tend to discourage litigation).